# Core Spotlight API - kUTTypeAudio play button in search result

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, corespotlight

Is it possible with the new Search API to have a play button in the search result cell?

I tried something like this:

```
let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeAudio as String)
...
attributeSet.contentType = kUTTypeAudio as String
attributeSet.contentURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath)
```

In the keynote they searched for a movie and got a result with a play button.
Maybe this is possible with later betas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Review the documents, that's always my favorite place to go with questions :). As far as Core Spotlight, if it is a viable feature, it's not publicly annotated on the documents Apple has provided us, so far. As you can see in the keynote, they were discussing Rich Results (dialing a phone number, playing a movie etc) during the index you spotted contained the Rich Result, more specifically during the [Web Markup API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW4) discussion, which is why you saw what you saw in the keynote. They annotate there are two ways for you to accomplish playing a movie or audio:

> You can also use schema markup to enable actions within rich results. For example, you might let users dial a phone number, get directions to an address, or play audio or video by integrating markup similar to the code shown here:

```
<!-- Two ways to enable playing audio or video. ->

<!-- Using Open Graph markup: ->
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://example.com/videofile">

<!-- Using Schema.org markup: ->
<div itemscope itemtype=
   "http://schema.org/AudioObject">
   <meta itemprop="contentUrl"
content="http://example.com/x.m4a" />
</div>
```

**SOURCE**

- [iOS9 What's New](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW1)
- [WWDC15 VIDEO](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW4)

Comment: There's no way to add the web markup inside a CoreSpotlight search item, is there?

Comment: Nope. Two different APIs.